# Python: How to avoid 'list assignment index out of range'

Tags: python

Tried a search but couldn't locate anything. I'm looking for the simplest to replace

```
if myList and len(myList)>4
```

with something shorter:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

if myList and len(myList)>4: 
    print myList[4], len(myList)
```

since

```
if not myList[4]
```

doesn't do job.

Comment: `if len(myList) > 4:` is shorter (and equivalent as long as `myList` is actually a `list`) ...

Comment: Normally you could just do `if len(myList) > 4`.  If you need the `if myList`, it's probbaly because of something else you're not showing here.

Comment: myList can arrive as None. I need to check that first...

Comment: @Sputnix be explicit then. `if myList is not None and len(myList)> 4:` Frankly I'd test for `None`-ness first and handle that case separately than just `if len(myList) <= 4`

Comment: if not myList Falses on an empty list too which works in my situation well. But thanks!

Comment: are you looking for just the last element of list?

Comment: No, it could be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try extending the built-in type `list` and override `__getitem__()` to get your intended behavior.

```
class MyList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index)
        except IndexError:
            return None

mylist = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
print mylist[4] #prints 5
print mylist[6] is None #prints True
```

Personally, I'd go for Adam Smith's suggestion.

Comment: I actually like yours! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure what's being asked, but I'll hazard a guess that [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) is the right concept here.

```
try:
    myList[4]
except IndexError:
    # handle it
```

Basically, try to do the thing you want to do with index 4. If you can't, and it's because of an `IndexError`, handle it the way you'd handle it if your `if len(myList) > 4` failed.

Comment: Good suggestion too. Wishing for shorter!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> if len(myList)> 4 : print myList[4]
```

***Update***

```
>>> if len(myList)> 4 and isinstance(myList,list) : print myList[4]
```

Comment: len(None) throws TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: well, in "a real life" there will be no way to anticipate what myList is.

Comment: Thanks! A check for None needs to proceed len() otherwise things get screwed really fast! :)

Comment: You should also use `isinstance(myList,list)` rather than `type(myList) is list` to preserve inheritance.